# MySQL statement construction

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, average, calculated-columns

I have a table in a MySql DB

| ID | USER_ID | BYTES | IP | Minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1293847777 | 1.0.001.111 | 3 |

I would like to do calculations on multiple columns.

- BYTES I would like to divide by a integer
- IP I would like to count
- IP I would like distinct count
- Minutes I would like to average

Then group by id and userid

Thanking you in advance

Comment: please provide few data as sample and expected output. bytes divide by integer means?

Comment: Use GROUP BY and according aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for your sample data. Use SUM() for summing up bytes then divide by integer. If no aggregate function is used in bytes column then either this column is used in group by clause or you get an error.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT id, user_id
     , SUM(bytes)/8 bytes
     , COUNT(ip) ip
     , COUNT(DISTINCT ip) dis_ip
     , AVG(minutes) minutes
FROM test
GROUP BY id, user_id
```

Please check from https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0275186699b9a5528005a70860952a42

If tables have multiple records then check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e6828e1cd11b1320ebf12a0777468c2

Comment: @JB_ please check this answer and let me know any query regard this.